# vue.js how to pass data object to store through an action

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to pass a data object to my vue store through an action.
This is how I'm passing it now.

```
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="addToCart(row)">Add to cart</button>

...mapActions(["addToCart"])
```

When I try to access my **row object** in my store.

```
addToCart({ commit }, row) {
            console.log("rooooooohhhhhoooow",this.row)
            //commit('mAddToCart',row)
        }
```

**row is undefined.**
how do I pass an object to store and access it with in the store?

Comment: `this.row` ? should be `row` ?

Comment: I tried it too. But the result is same

Comment: This looks correct. Isn't the problem somewhere else?

Comment: and what is row? show more code or try to log row before make dispatch. because your code looks like correct

Comment: `@click="addToCart(row)"` Where is your `row` coming from?

Answer (score -1):

I have not been able to test this as I am on my tablet, but think what you want is the following. In the calling component:

```
this.$store.dispatch({
    type: ‘addToCart’,
    row: row
})
```

In your store actions:

```
addToCart ({commit, state}, payload) => {
    console.log(`ROW: ${payload.row})
    commit({
        type: ‘mAddToCart’,
        row: payload.row
    })
})
```

The in your mutations:

```
mAddToCart((state, payload) => {
    // Do what you need to do with payload.row
})
```

Hope that helps.